# GIF Killer! Stop animated gifs in the Chat

Tags: script, chat, bookmarklet

### About

Bookmarklet that stops GIFs in their tracks! <sub>until you refresh..</sub>

GIFs are replaced with the following image:
[image: I was once an annoying GIF]

#### How to use.

Depending on your browser you create a new bookmark, copy and paste the code below in the Location field, then name it something cool like ***GIF KILLER!***. *Voila!*
This Bookmarklet was designed for the SE/SO Chats, and it's purpose is not to block Animated GIFs but to allow you to stop viewing them after you have had a good *lol*.

#### License

GIF KILLER is released under the [WTFPL](http://sam.zoy.org/wtfpl/).

#### Download

You can download the code or just *Fork* it here:
https://gist.github.com/3403863
Either version will work for the chat, however the none jQuery version will guarantee to work for all sites (modern browsers).

### Contact

I can be reached at `rob.lemon@gmail.com`.

### Code

```
javascript:$('img').filter(function() { if( this.src.substr(-3).toUpperCase() === 'GIF' ) return this; }).replaceWith('<img src="http://i.imgur.com/vMgrL.png" />');;
```

Comment: You might also consider the [Unicorn Software License](http://quickmediasolutions.com/unicorn) :)

Comment: @NathanOsman it turns out... any license that isn't going to work when you click on it is probably not the one you want to link to (though it might be OK to transclude it in the documentation).